# React Native Absolute Positioned Component elements onPress events not working

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a custom dropdown component which has a transparent Scrollview with ToucableOpacity elements. However the onPress on them are not working, even though, zIndex is making them appear on top of everything else.

In the main screen, I created two elements, 1 header containing the Dropdown and 2nd one is the body which contains the rest. Its code is given below:

```
     <View style={styles.body, {zIndex:0}}>
            <View style={[styles.header,{zIndex:1}]}>
                <Text style={styles.header_text}>Search In </Text>
                <Dropdown items={CATEGORIES}/>
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.main,{zIndex:-1}]}>
                <Text style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}>I am the body</Text>
            </View>
     <View>
```

I have included the render event markup of the Dropdown element. Its code is given below:

```
       <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.main_container} onPress={this.animate}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.selectedCategoryText}</Text>
                <Text>-V-</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={{zIndex:3}}>
                <Animated.View style={[styles.animated_container,{opacity: this.opacity, zIndex:4}]}>
                    <ScrollView style={{height:60,zIndex:4}}>
                        { this.data.map( (item, i)=>
                             <TouchableOpacity 
                                style={{zIndex:5}}
                                disabled={this.state.disabled} 
                                key={i} 
                                onPress={()=>this.selectItem(i)}>
                                    <Text >{item} {i}</Text>
                              </TouchableOpacity>
                             )}
                    </ScrollView>

                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        </View>
```

Styles for Dropdown are:

```
    container:{
       zIndex:2
    },
    main_container:{
       flexDirection: 'row',zIndex:2
   },
   text:{
      fontFamily: fontStyles.PoppinsRegular,
      fontSize: moderateScale(14)
   },
   animated_container:{
      backgroundColor: colors.secondaryWhiteColor,
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      zIndex:3
  }
```

Screenshot is given as. zIndex makes the elements appear on top but i cannot trigger onPress on Toucable opacities.

[image]

Comment: I have looked at other similar question in which adding zIndex to the parent element fixed issues. However, I have added zIndex to parent, but it doesn't seems to work. I am really not understanding what exactly is the problem.

Comment: in Android, instead of `zIndex` try `elevation` it will work

Comment: Applied elevation 4,5,6 on AnimatedViews, ScrollView and ToucableOpacities. Nothing happened.

Comment: @Rusty, have you found a solution for this yet? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: i am also facing same issue. Did anyone find the solution for that